# What is the difference between "claim" and "redeem"?

Tags: word-usage

These words are usually used in the context of promotional codes, or top-up cards. They seem to be used both in the same context of "converting code to actual value" (e.g. code→account balance, code→gift). Is there a difference in their meaning or connotation?

For example:

- Claim/Redeem your code
- Claimed/Redeemed rewards

Comment: Please cite research you've done to try to resolve this.  In this case you might also note whether this is BrE or AmE, as the usage might differ.

Comment: I've searched the internet for examples of usage. I hoped that I'd get an answer from a native speaker on which use when, along with any possible differences in BrE/AmE. Honestly I don't know where to do any other reasearch on this. 

I would be able to answer question like this in Czech. Therefore I though it's safe to assume that English native speaker should be able to do the same.

Comment: Claim and redeem are very similar in this use.  Usually, in AmE we claim (take) a reward and redeem (exchange) a voucher, credit, or code for that reward. Note that 'i.e.' introduces a summary or simplified restatement, whereas 'e.g.' introduces examples like a balance or a gift.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification as well for i.e./e.g. correction. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reward programs use fanciful language to (mis)represent what is going on.  But in terms of word definitions:

**Claim** means to assert that something is yours.  In the context of reward programs, this is the "you've already won" case.  It is your prize and they are just holding it for you until you demonstrate that you are the rightful owner.  That might involve providing a promotional code or giving them your address, phone number, and other personal information to "prove" who you are.  *See [M-W #2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/claim).*

Again in the context of a rewards program, **redeem** means to exchange or trade something of value (like a coupon or code) for something else (like a prize or product).  It also has a somewhat relevant meaning of to get back something that is or was yours ("you've already won"), by exchanging some placeholder for it (like a a coupon or code).  *See [M-W especially #5b2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redeem).*